# Getting MAX value returned SQL command c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, max

I'm trying to get the MAX value returned but it keeps returning 0.

```
string stateValue = "CA";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Population) FROM TestData WHERE State=" + stateValue);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Population", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
DBConnection.Instance.execNonQuery(cmd);

int population = (int)cmd.Parameters["@Population"].Value;
```

In `DBConnection` class this is the `execNonQuery` function:

```
public int execNonQuery(string sCmd, CommandType cmdType)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sCmd, m_sqlDataBase);
    cmd.CommandType = cmdType;

    try
    {
        m_sqlDataBase.Open();
    }
    catch { }

    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter direction is used with Stored Procedures. Here you are simply executing a single query. You need to use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method, since you will only get back one result. It returns an `object` so you have to convert it to `int` before using it.

Also your code is using string concatenation to create SQL Query and it is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Also consider using [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) with your Command and Connection.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Popluation) FROM TestData WHERE State=@state"))
{
    //Associate connection with your command an open it
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", stateValue);
    int populuation = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: This worked.  I just changed the lines:  
                           int populuation = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();  and kept the rest of it the same

Answer (score 3):

The ExecuteNonQuery call does not return the result of executing your query.

You can use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) or Execute to get the value back.

```
    public int execQuery(string sCmd, CommandType cmdType)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sCmd, m_sqlDataBase);
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        try
        {
            m_sqlDataBase.Open();


            return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        catch { 
             // handle your error but don't trap it here..
             throw;
        }
    }
```

ExecuteScalar is a short-circuit for getting the first value, or the first result set. You can use it to return a single value out of a query, such as yours.

Another option is to use the Execute method to obtain a result set and then use that to get the value you're after:

```
    public int execQuery(string sCmd, CommandType cmdType)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sCmd, m_sqlDataBase);
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        try
        {
            m_sqlDataBase.Open();

            using(var dataReader = cmd.Execute())
            {
                if (dataReader.Read())
                {
                      return Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { 
             // handle your error but don't trap it here..
             throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout

```
  var sql = string.Format("SELECT MAX(Popluation) FROM TestData WHERE State='{0}'", stateValue);
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
```

(The important part was adding the single quotes. The string.Format was to make it look pretty)

Comment: I tired it but didn't help.  It does look pretty though.